# Can I invite friends to Steam? 

Tags: steam

I basically want to invite a friend to steam, so that they will download it and play a certain game with me.  Does steam have this sort of feature? It's essentially a personalized share.

Alternatively, since the game isn't super expensive, I would be willing to gift it to them, which I think you can do to an email address (not necessarily linked to an account).

Comment: Just did a quick test with the add a friend functionality.  Entering an email address doesn't seem to allow you to send a friend request to that email if it isn't already in the Steam users database.  From this, my inclination is to say no, it isn't possible.

Comment: dang, but thanks for checking it out for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no feature to allow you to invite a friend to Steam as such.  The closest thing I can think of is either to:

### Gift them a game

If you have a game in your Steam inventory, you can gift that to an email address that is not already on Steam.

[image: Sample gift send page]

This will send them an email with an invite to Steam and all the instructions they will need.

### Do it manually

1. Navigate to https://store.steampowered.com/join/
2. Fill in your details and click `CREATE MY ACCOUNT`
3. Get them to download the [Steam client](http://store.steampowered.com/about/).
4. Send them to your Steam profile page, "http://steamcommunity.com/id/{Your ID or Username}/".
5. Tell them to send you a friend request and then you can accept it.
6. Tell them to download your chosen game.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is possible. The gifting feature definitely is though.

Just have your friend download Steam.